# Sum multiple values returned vertically from vlookup

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following table which I need to have all the values found from multiple ranges vertically.
I was using the following formula, but I'm only getting 1 result and not 7. After getting all those 7 values, I need to add them together in order to get a total.

So far my guess was to try the 2nd formula but obviously is not returning what I need but maybe is something around those corners.

```js
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E4,{range0,range1,range2,range3,range4,range5,range6},5,false)))

=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E4,{range0,range1,range2,range3,range4,range5,range6},{5,5,5,5,5,5,5},false)))
```

Comment: The issue is that, your `ARRAYFORMULA` outputs 7 numbers BUT your `SUM` added them into 1. By removing `SUM`, you would have 7 numbers now but I'm not sure if it is the data you want. Show a sample sheet and its expected output so we can adjust your formula.

Comment: Yes I want to add them into 1, but still I'm not getting 7 values but 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FILTER` instead:

#### Formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER(B6:F, B6:B = "name1"),,5))
```

Use `FILTER` to get the rows of `B6:F` where "name1" is found in `B6:B`
Use `INDEX` to get only the specific column which is in our case, `5`
Then `SUM` the column.

Comment: This definitely works! Thank you so much, Octavia!